# Laravel one to many relationship trouble

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

have 15 one to many tables in DB and everything works fine, but now when i tried to add one more table i got this error. I tried 5-6 solutions from google but i cant resolve problem. artikal_naruzba table work fine. My all tables are empty!

Error

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]

    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add`enter code here` foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `Narudzbe` add constraint narudzbe_kupac_id_foreign foreign key (`kupac_id`) references `kupci` (`id`))

      [PDOException]
      SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Table Narudzba

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Narudzbe', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('kupac_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('kupac_id')->unsigned()->references('id')->on('kupci');
            $table->integer('BrojNarudzbe');
            $table->boolean('Status')->default(1);
            $table->boolean('Otkazano')->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });



        Schema::create('artikal_naruzba', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('artikal_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('artikal_id')->references('id')->on('artikli')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->integer('narudzba_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('narudzba_id')->references('id')->on('Narudzbe')->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->timestamps();
        });

    }
```

Table Kupac

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('kupci', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('ime');
            $table->string('prezime');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('lozinka', 60);
            $table->string('telefon', 30);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Naruzba model

```
class Narudzba extends Model {

    protected $table = 'Narudzbe';

    public function kupac(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Kupac');
    }

    public function artikli(){

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Artikal');
    }
}
```

Kupac Model

```
class Kupac extends Model {

    protected $table = 'kupci';

    public function narudzba(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Narudzba');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declareing   `narudzba_id` in `artikal_naruzba` table unsigned data type. 
But your original `Narudzbe` table has id without specifying  unsigned which you are referencing as foreign key in `artikal_naruzba`

Please carefully check both field data types and length.May be there is mismatch.
For further please go through:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#foreign-keys

```
$table->integer('narudzba_id')->unsigned()->index();
                $table->foreign('narudzba_id')->references('id')->on('Narudzbe')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: I have problem with Kupac - Narudzba relationship